# Auto create folder and upload image in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have created `..\frontend\web\uploads`.

This is the function `Create` in `PropertiesControllers.php` configuration that I have:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Properties();

        $date = date('YmdHis');

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {            
            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'url_img');
            if (!empty($file))
                $model->url_img = $date.$file;

            if($model->save())
            {
             if (!empty($file))
              $file->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/uploads/'.$date.$file);

              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

It works when `uploads` is existed. But I want to redirect to new folder in `uploads` as `uploads\img`

```
if (!empty($file))
                  $file->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/uploads/img'.$date.$file);
```

It show error because `../web/uploads/img` is not existed.

I don't know to solve this issue. Help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to create the `img` folder before `$file->saveAs(`. In Yii2,you can make use of `yii\helpers\FileHelper` to create a directory. If your problem is like img folder does not exists inside uploads,then you can create the folder with `yii\helpers\FileHelper` as

```
$path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend')."/web/uploads/img";
\yii\helpers\FileHelper::createDirectory($path, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true);
```

Full code

```
public function actionCreate() {

        $model = new Properties();

        $date = date('YmdHis');

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'url_img');
            if (!empty($file))
                $model->url_img = $date . $file;

            if ($model->save()) {   


                if (!empty($file)) {
                    $path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . "/web/uploads/img";
                    //here you create the folder
                    if (\yii\helpers\FileHelper::createDirectory($path, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true)) {
                        $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/uploads/img/' . $date . $file);
                    }
                }    

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

More info about FileHelper here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-filehelper.html